# Why does the value not change when I define a single call?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why does the value not change when I define a single call?

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
       Touch screentouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
       var j1 = joint1.transform.position;
       var j2 = joint2.transform.position;
       if (screentouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
       {
         if (distance)
         {
            j1 = j2; // no work???
         }
        }
       }
```

but I use below one is find.

```
       j1 = j2; replace to
       joint1.transform.position = joint2.transform.position; is ok
```

what can i do , if i want to use var j1 to replace long  joint1.transform.position;
Thanks

Comment: what do you want to achieve? j1 is a reference, so j1 = j2 just changes reference, not value

Comment: Your code is not complete; it's very hard to understand what you are trying to achive... please add a minimal reproducible code snippet and a clear explanation of what is your target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a variable `a` can change another variable `b` only when `b` is referenced to `a`.

This is possible in C++

```
int x = 10;
int &ref = x // ref is referenced to x

ref = 20; // ref is assigned a new value and hence x is also modified

cout << x; // prints 20
```

There is no solution for this in C#, as using pointers or references (if exist) in C# is considered unsafe. Even if you try to use pointers in C#, you get an error saying:

```
error CS0214: Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context
```

However, in your question, to update `joint1.transform.position`, as you can't use references in C#, you can just write

```
joint1.transform.position = j2 // assigns joint2.transform.position to joint1.transform.position
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not applying the assignment. When you call:

```
var j1 = joint1.transform.position;
var j2 = joint2.transform.position;
```

you're getting the current positions for `joint1` and `joint2`. When you assign `j1 = j2`, you're just changing the `Vector3` value for `j1`, you're not actually changing the position.

If you're wanting `joint1` to actually move then you need to set its position:

```
joint1.transform.position = j1;
```